# Eager Loading Error: 'Call to a member function

Tags: laravel, function, eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I encountered an error and don't know why to add this error indicated : "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int".

I have a WarehouseProduct model with relation.

```
class WarehouseProduct extends Model{
        protected $fillable = [
            'free_amount',
            'booked_amount',
            // ...
        ];


    public function getPhysicalAmount() {
        return $this->free_amount + $this->booked_amount;
    }

    public function getValueOfPhysicalAmount() {
        return $this->getPhysicalAmount() * $this->incoming_unit_price *
            $this->getDailyExchangeRate()->exchange_rate;
    }

    public function getValueOfPhysicalAmountInForeignDeviza() {
        return $this->getPhysicalAmount() * $this->incoming_unit_price;
    }
}
```

and i have a search function in the controller

```
public function search(Request $request) {
        $result = null;

        $result = $this->warehouseProductRepository
        ->detailed_search($request)
        ->with([
            'getValueOfPhysicalAmountInForeignDeviza',
            'getValueOfPhysicalAmount',
            'getPhysicalAmount',
        ]);
        // ...
}
```

When the program runs it gives an error on these, could anyone help why?

Comment: the with method is suposed to be used with relationships to lazy load another models. You dont need do lazy load them as they are properties of your model and not a relationship.

Comment: I see, but I would need them to add them somehow.

Comment: You can just remove the 'with' part  of your search and theyll be available as valueOfPhysicalAmountInForeignDeviza (without the 'get' part);

Like: $result->valueOfPhysicalAmountInForeignDeviza;